# Java REST-Service with Digital Signing

Tags: java, rest, security, encryption, rsa

I have a small REST-Service which a handfull of clients connect to. Now I need to make sure that request comes only from my clients and the response only from my server. I don't need to encrypt the data because it doesn't matter if someone can read it, it is just important noone can enter wrong data.

Now my idea was to use digital signation with public and private keys (RSA). What's really important is the speed of the algorithm.

Is this the right idea? How do I implent this in JAX-RS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is pretty fast and it's rather secure (compared to most home-brew stuff anyway). OK, it also provides confidentiality, but that should be OK. Using TLS - possibly with self signed certificates - probably makes most sense. You have pretty fast algorithms here, such as `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`.

ECDSA using SHA-512 probably makes most sense if you want to go for application level security (signing the requests / responses) possibly using a CMS container format. Note that you may have to protect against replay attacks if you go this route. The chances of screwing this up are much higher though.

ECDSA is much faster than RSA for private key operations, so it should definitely be preferred over RSA when high efficiency is required (unless RSA is still fast enough, something that may very well be the case).